# Printing an output as a table

Tags: python, pandas

I have an output as follows.

```
  output=  {(0, 0): 50.0, (0, 1): 100.0, (0, 2): 100.0, (0, 3): 100.0, 
    (1, 0): 0, (1, 1): 0, (1, 2): 200.0, (1, 3): 75.0, 
    (2, 0): 0, (2, 1): 150.0, (2, 2): 150.0, (2, 3): 0, 
    (3, 0): 500.0, (3, 1): 500.0, (3, 2): 500.0, (3, 3): 500.0, 
    (4, 0): 0, (4, 1): 0, (4, 2): 5550.0, (4, 3):0 }
```

I need to put these values in a table using pandas data frame to get the below output

```
value=[aa,bb,cc,dd]
name=[a,b,c,d,e]

    aa        bb     cc     dd
a   50.0    100.0   100.0   100.0
b   0         0     200.0   75.0
c   0       150.0   150.0    0
d   500.0   500.0   500.0   500.0
e   0         0     5500.0   0
```

Could you advise how to do that using a for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read it with `pd.Series` , since the tuple will convert to multiple index, then do `unstack` and assign your column and index name

```
s=pd.Series(output).unstack()
s
       0      1       2      3
0   50.0  100.0   100.0  100.0
1    0.0    0.0   200.0   75.0
2    0.0  150.0   150.0    0.0
3  500.0  500.0   500.0  500.0
4    0.0    0.0  5550.0    0.0
```

Comment: Hi @YOBEN_S Thanks.It did work,But In my last column is starting with a new line showing \ sign at last.Do you know how we can prevent this

Comment: @suresh_chinthy in the sample data it dose not include /

Comment: Yes.I found the issue.We need to adjust the jupyter notebook output width to a large number by below.pd.set_option("display.width", 170)

Comment: Hi @YOBEN_S do you know how to convert this to bar graph using pyplot package.For an example x Axis: aa,bb,cc,dd  and group by a,b,c,d,e y Axis: the values.If you have any idea really appreciated